# Tube won't inflate or deflate

Tags: presta

I have presta valves, and I got tubes with green goo about a year ago. I didn't ride my bike a lot, but I'm riding it more now, but the rear tire can't inflate or deflate. It's full enough that I cant get the wheel tire off the tube, but flat enough that it's hard/dangerous to ride. I'm thinking the green goo clogged up the valve somehow, but I'm not sure how to fix that. Is there a way to get the tire off the tube while it's still mostly inflated? I have thought of trying to poke a hole in the tube somehow, but I can't lift the tire away to do that.

Comment: With a pair of pliers you can (sometimes) unscrew the inside part of the valve.  Then, if necessary, poke a wire through to clear out some of the goop.  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/35083/is-it-normal-for-a-presta-valve-to-unscrew-into-two-pieces

Comment: It does unscrew?  Is it removable.

Comment: Most likely, you're going to end up getting a new tube. And don't slime (goo) it unless necessary (most people are better off with a good tire and a regular / extra thick tube). And proper tire inflation.

Comment: Your best option is to flat the tube.  Hammer a fairly slim nail through a fat part of the tyre (ie through a lug) then pull the nail out.  Tube will loose air, then you can take the tyre off and the tube.  Fit a new tube and inflate like normal.  Tubes are cheap and consumable.  Doing it this way saves the tyre, which are worth 5-10x  the cost of a tube.