# How do you deflate a tire with a presta valve

Tags: tire

I can't deflate my tire which has a presta valve so that I can put a new tube on the tire.  I made this video so that you can see what I'm doing.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the valve core with pliers and replace it.

Comment: Air never gets released when the knurled nut is screwed in. It only gets released when the knurled nut is screwed out, as at :20. Screw out, then press *harder* with the bowl of a spoon (so it doesn't slip off and you don't impale your thumb). If pressing *harder* doesn't release air, then your valve is frozen, so your tube is toast.

Comment: @R.Chung Some tubes, such as those made by Continental and maybe some others, have removable valve cores, which allow the use of valve extenders for deep rims.  One could save the valve cores from unusable tubes...  (And yes, if you have a screw-on pump chuck sometimes it's those removable valve cores that unscrew and come off with the pump chuck when you're done pumping.  A careful application of blue loctite fixes that tube.)

Comment: DON'T unscrew the outer nut that holds the valve in place.  Unscrew the inner tiny knobbie and then press on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track and are doing everything right, but the valve itself has failed to work.

Wind the little acorn nut out some as per 17-seconds.  Don't try and force it off though, it won't come off completely.  Then push the valve down harder in the same way you have been.

The silver threadded ring at  27-seconds is only there to hold the valve stem in place and protect the rim from energetic pumping.  While it needs to be removed to get the tube off, it won't be affecting the air flow.

---

If that doesn't work, you may be able to remove the stuck valve. Some valves have a removable core - you may be able to unthread the core and let the air come out easier.  This is well-documented in [Is it normal for a presta valve to unscrew into two pieces?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/35083/is-it-normal-for-a-presta-valve-to-unscrew-into-two-pieces)

---

Your final options are more brutal.  Presuming you want to save and reuse the tyre, then

- You could either lever the tyre off with the tube half-inflated.
- Lever a section of bead up and slip a sharp knife in between bead and rim to puncture the tube.
- Use some small bolt cutters to cut the valve off completely (take the knurled ring off first)  This may cause a sudden release of pressure, so I'd suggest not using a power tool.

If the tyre is also due for replacement, you could simply cut through that as well, but it seems to have life left based on video.

---

As for a root cause, I wonder if you have sealant in this tyre and it has gummed up the valve internally.  A replacement core might have fixed this, but many tubes lack them.

I bet you can't inflate the tube either, using any form of pump which is what has forced the tube replacement.

Good luck!  You can do this.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate that.